# No data showing on Google Analytics due to Profile/Filter Configuration

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics Flex API to record data from a Flex application.

As I understand it, Google Analytics has a 3-tier hierarchy: An Account can contain one or more Properties, each of which can contain one or more Profiles. A UA code is associated with a Property, and Filters can be used to record specific traffic to a specific Profile.

The application lives on 5 different server environments (development, staging, live, etc) and we need to separate the data from the different environments.

Note that the server environments do *not* live within the same domain name. For example, staging is at staging.x.com, but the live version is at www.y.com. But I want them all to share the same UA code, so we are tracking them as 5 different Profiles.

So I have one Property with multiple Profiles. I set up a Filter for each Profile saying "Include only traffic form the domains that are equal to" and the particular hostname for that server environment.

The "Default URL" for the Property is set to the hostname of the default Profile, which is the live environment.

We set up that configuration yesterday, and today there is no data in any of our Profiles. We had data the day before (before doing the reconfiguration). I am confident that the tracking code in the client app is sending the hits to GA, since I can see them in Chrome debug mode, and the client app wasn't changed between the day before yesterday and yesterday. The only thing that changed was the configuration of the Property and the Profiles.

So obviously I'm missing something about Property and Profile configuration. Some specific questions:

- Am I understanding Filters correctly? Is it somehow applying the Filter to the entire Property? It seemed like the Filters were at the Profile level.
- Does the "Default URL" for the Property have an effect on which hits are recorded? What exactly is it used for?
- Is there some restriction on how the Profiles within a Property can be affiliated? For example, do they *have to* belong to the same domain name? I thought not, but maybe I'm wrong?
- Any other suggestions?

Obviously, I can experiment with the configuration and see what happens. But I have to wait until the next day to see the effects of each change. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is the include filter for the hostname the only include filter on each profile? Did you set up a "raw" profile that doesn't have any filters on it? This is a best practice so you don't get zero data after applying filters. Did you set the domain for each one in the tracking code ? `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domainnamehere.com']);` See [Tracking Multiple Domains](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html) for additional info.

Comment: I'm using the GA Flex SDK which doesn't have _gaq.push. What does _gaq.push actually do, in terms of the HTTP calls that are made to the GA server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I understanding Filters correctly? Is it somehow applying the
>   Filter to the entire Property? It seemed like the Filters were at the
>   Profile level.

Yes Filters are always applied at the profile level.

> Does the "Default URL" for the Property have an effect on which hits
>   are recorded? What  exactly is it used for?

The "Default URL" has no effect on data collection or filtering at all. It's only used to create links from the page reports back to your site. So when you see the top page being /index.html and you click the little link beside it it will take you to "Default URL"/index.html . So you might break that specific feature if the url doesn't exist on you domain. But for the sake of reporting it's completely fine to use a different url.

> Is there some restriction on how the Profiles within a Property can be
>   affiliated? For example, do they have to belong to the same domain
>   name? I thought not, but maybe I'm wrong?

No, the Profiles inside a Web Property don't need to share the same domain name. It's perfectly fine to have multiple profiles filtered by hostname and it's completely fine and normal to have a global profile with data from multiple hostnames. In that last case the data may be a little off unless you implement [Cross Domain Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html).

> Any other suggestions?

It seems that you have a very good understanding of how things work in GA. One thing that you might have missed and @jk commented about is that you should always have an unfiltered profile on you Web Property to avoid losing data due to bad filters.

Another thing to notice is that in the past I had problems with the predefined domain filters. It seems they were being aplied to the wrong field inside Google Analytics. I think they were being applied to the "Visitor ISP Organization". For that reason I never use predefined filters. So if you are using predefined filters you might consider changing them to Custom Include fields, select the "Hostname" metric and enter the domain you want to filter as a RegExp. I believe this bug should be fixed by now, but you never know, I just lost confidence in the predefined filters on that day.

If you acidentaly used 2 include filters in a profile that filter on the hostname but with different values chances are they are canceling each other. So you might want to go into each profile and check if they only contain one include filter each.

eg:

- Include only trafic from x.com
- Include only trafic from y.com

This will result in a profile with no data.

Another thing to notice is that filters don't apply to retroactive data. So if you apply a filter today to a profile it will only filter data from now on. Data that has already been processed will be elft untouched. There's no way to change data that has been added to a profile, nor to add retroactive data to a new profile.

Other than that you are probably good.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I've changed all the filters to custom include filters by hostname, using regular expression syntax. And I've added an unfiltered profile so I can see the traffic in aggregate in case the filters are incorrectly configured. If this works (we'll know tomorrow), then I'll checkmark your answer.